# Spark SQL Join multiple failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, left-join

I have about 18 DataSet each of which contains 10 different columns and 1k~10k rows and I have to do a left join on all of them one by one.

When I do:

```scala
b = a.join(A, 'one column', 'outer_left').dictinct() 
c = b.join(B, 'one column', 'outer_left').dictinct()
d = c.join(C, 'one column', 'outer_left').dictinct()
... 
n = m.join(M, 'one column', 'outer_left').dictinct()
n.write()
```

it works.

but then I would like to optimize the code like this:

```scala
val data = List(a, A, B, C, ..., N, M)
val joined = data.reduce((left, right) => left.join(right, 'one column', 'outer_left').distinct()) 
val result = joined.distinct()  // this one works
result.write()  // this one doesn't work




18/02/28 09:54:35 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_45_90 !
18/02/28 09:54:35 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_108_191 !
[Stage 63:>                                                       (1 + 4) / 200]18/02/28 09:54:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.1 in stage 63.3 (TID 12686, 127.0.0.1, executor 8): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=11, mapId=-1, reduceId=4, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 11
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:693)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ShuffledRowRDD.compute(ShuffledRowRDD.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1729)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:186)
... 44 more
```

Comment: I guess you are mixing python and scala codes in the question

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"// this one doesn't work"_? What makes you think/know it does not work?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Hi, I say it work or not based on the Application Detail UI from localhost:8080. When it doesnot work, I get many exceptions.

Comment: Show one so we also learn something from you (and perhaps help you fix it). Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Hi, I added part of the exception detail, but it is really too verbose, I'm not that will help understanding the problem. This is the exception when there is no **broadcast** for the **join**.

Comment: So, the question now would be why it works with broadcast while it does not without?! Isn't it the real question? You may have earned time but the problem could still be there, couldn't it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski yep, now the question would be why *broadcast* makes it work. When I posted the question, I didn't try yet *broadcast*, that's why later I posted the answer to make it program work but I still don't know exactly what is the difference. I know **broadcast** force the smaller dataframe to be sent to the larger one, maybe that is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

my second solution which didn't work at first time becomes a working one by a small modification with **broadcast**.

```
val data = List(a, A, B, C, ..., N, M)
val joined = data.reduce((left, right) => left.join(broadcast(right), 'one column', 'outer_left').distinct()) 
val result = joined.distinct()  // this one works
result.write()  // this one work now
```

Answer (score 0):

In scala, `foldLeft` is a very beautiful function that can be used to meet your requirement.

I have *three* `dataframes` as you have *18*

```
a
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  0|    2|
|  1|    5|
|  2|    1|
|  3|    3|
|  4|    8|
+---+-----+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)


A
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|Cliff|
|  2|  Raj|
|  3| Alim|
|  4| Jose|
|  5| Jeff|
+---+-----+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)


B
+---+------+
| id|number|
+---+------+
|  1|   100|
|  2|   200|
|  3|   300|
|  4|   400|
|  5|   500|
+---+------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: integer (nullable = false)
```

**Your working way**

You are joining in serialized manner as following

```scala
val joined = a.join(A, Seq("id"), "leftouter").join(B, Seq("id"), "leftouter")
```

which should give you

```
+---+-----+-----+------+
|id |value|name |number|
+---+-----+-----+------+
|0  |2    |null |null  |
|1  |5    |Cliff|100   |
|2  |1    |Raj  |200   |
|3  |3    |Alim |300   |
|4  |8    |Jose |400   |
+---+-----+-----+------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
```

**foldLeft way**

Now if we do the same in `foldLeft` function

```scala
val data = List(A, B)
val joined = data.foldLeft(a)((left, right) => left.join(right, Seq("id"), "leftouter"))
```

You should get the same result. I hope the answer is helpful for you to uderstand your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if you look at my not-working solution, *reduce* is similar to your *foldLeft* and neither of them work because of the data size.

Comment: did you try it? By the way is that scala or python in your question? and what version of spark are you using?

Comment: yes, I already tried **reduce** and **foldLeft/fold** before posting the question and I use scala.

Comment: I think it is not the version and I use spark2.2.1. It is the size which causes the problem.

Comment: I am asking the version because `outer_left` keyword is not recognized in my version of scala spark 2.2.0. Glad to see your working answer below :)

Comment: sorry about the typo but it is **left_outer** in the code :)

Comment: there is no hyphen too I guess. :)